# All emails are going to spam

Tags: email, postfix, plesk

So, i purchased a dedicated server just over a month ago and its running CentOS (Plesk).

Every email that is sent out to gmail accounts are going to spam, and its not happening to any other email provider.

I've completed the following;
SPF
DKIM
DMARC
Reverse DNS

But still no luck, this is a massive inconvenience to our business and is having a massive impact and im stumped at what to do.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Google, rather than with Unix and Linux _per se_.

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons why gmail might classify your mail as spam:

1. Are you actually sending spam?  That includes adding people to mailing lists without their explicit consent and confirmation.
2. If you are running a legit opt-in list, do your mailouts provide an easy and obvious way to unsubscribe?  Without that, some users will just "Report Spam" to gmail instead of expending any effort to figure out how to unsub.
3. Has your IP address been used to send spam in the past?
4. Has your domain been used to send spam in the past?
5. Do the emails you are sending out look spammish in appearance or method (e.g. forged sender, mangled or missing date header)?
6. Is your ISP a known haven for spammers?

Comment: 7. Did you register your domain just when you purchased the server?  New domains look suspicious to spam filters.